# What's the fastest way to fixup line-endings for SMTP sending?

Tags: python, smtp, performance

I'm coding a email application that produces messages for sending via SMTP.  That means I need to change all lone \n and \r characters into the canonical \r\n sequence we all know and love.  Here's the code I've got now:

```
CRLF = '\r\n'
msg = re.sub(r'(?<!\r)\n', CRLF, msg)
msg = re.sub(r'\r(?!\n)', CRLF, msg)
```

The problem is it's not very fast.  On large messages (around 80k) it takes up nearly 30% of the time to send a message!

Can you do better?  I eagerly await your Python gymnastics.

Comment: Have you seen Lamson? http://lamsonproject.org

Comment: That's an SMTP server, right?  I'm writing a sending app. I don't see how it's applicable.

Comment: Note: I'm looking for a *faster* implementation.  I appreciate all the help but so far all the suggestions have been slower!

Comment: @samtregar: Lamson is not just a SMTP server and is designed to ease the development of "sending app"s. At least read the FAQ before dismissing it as non applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I don't really want to switch to a new sending framework right now though - the app is almost done and just needs a speedup!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex helped:

`re.sub(r'\r\n|\r|\n', '\r\n', msg)`

But this code ended up winning:

`msg.replace('\r\n','\n').replace('\r','\n').replace('\n','\r\n')`

The original regexes took .6s to convert /usr/share/dict/words from \n to \r\n, the new regex took .3s, and the replace()s took .08s.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is the fact that inserting an extra character in the middle of the string is killing it.

When you are substituting the text "hello \r world" it has to actually increase the size of the entire string by one character to "hello \r\n world" .

I would suggest looping over the string and looking at characters one by one. If it is not a \r or \n then just append it to the new string. If it is a \r or \n append the new string with the correct values

Code in C# (converting to python should be trivial)

```
        string FixLineEndings(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            return string.Empty;

        StringBuilder rv = new StringBuilder(input.Length);

        for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = input[i];
            if (c != '\r' && c != '\n')
            {
                rv.Append(c);
            }
            else if (c == '\n')
            {
                rv.Append("\r\n");
            }
            else if (c == '\r')
            {
                if (i == input.Length - 1)
                {
                    rv.Append("\r\n"); //a \r at the end of the string
                }
                else if (input[i + 1] != '\n')
                {
                    rv.Append("\r\n");
                }

            }
        }

        return rv.ToString();
    }
```

This was interesting enough to go write up a sample program to test. I used the regex given in the other answer and the code for using the regex was:

static readonly Regex _r1 = new Regex(@"(?

I tried with a bunch of test cases. The outputs are:

```
------------------------
Size: 1000 characters
All\r
        String: 00:00:00.0038237
        Regex : 00:00:00.0047669
All\r\n
        String: 00:00:00.0001745
        Regex : 00:00:00.0009238
All\n
        String: 00:00:00.0024014
        Regex : 00:00:00.0029281
No \r or \n
        String: 00:00:00.0000904
        Regex : 00:00:00.0000628
\r at every 100th position and \n at every 102th position
        String: 00:00:00.0002232
        Regex : 00:00:00.0001937
------------------------
Size: 10000 characters
All\r
        String: 00:00:00.0010271
        Regex : 00:00:00.0096480
All\r\n
        String: 00:00:00.0006441
        Regex : 00:00:00.0038943
All\n
        String: 00:00:00.0010618
        Regex : 00:00:00.0136604
No \r or \n
        String: 00:00:00.0006781
        Regex : 00:00:00.0001943
\r at every 100th position and \n at every 102th position
        String: 00:00:00.0006537
        Regex : 00:00:00.0005838
```

which show the string replacing function doing better in cases where the number of \r and \n's are high. For regular use though the original regex approach is much faster (see the last set of test cases - the ones w/o \r\n and with few \r's and \n's)

This was of course coded in C# and not python but i'm guessing there would be similarities in the run times across languages

Comment: I'd be completely shocked if this was faster.  Walking a string character by character has to be slower than the regex engine, doesn't it?

Comment: i think that it is the fact that each time he hits a \r or \n the stirng is going to be expanded that is hurting. the only way to know is to run both approaches and see :)

Comment: see perf related info above. test cases etc were very simple and i used the regex below

Comment: Yup, no shock, it's 10x slower. Thanks for playing though!

Comment: updated again - the original regex's that you provided are infact faster when there are fewer \r's and \n's.

Don't have python here :(

Comment: Python is free, you can install it anywhere you want!

Answer (score 1):

Replace them on the fly as you're writing the string to wherever it's going.  If you use a regex or anything else you'll be making two passes: one to replace the characters and then one to write it.  Deriving a new Stream class and wrapping it around whatever you're writing to is pretty effective; that's the way we do it with System.Net.Mail and that means I can use the same stream encoder for writing to both files and network streams.  I'd have to see some of your code in order to give you a really good way to do this though.  Also, keep in mind that the actual replacement won't really be any faster, however the total execution time would be reduced since you're only making one pass instead of two (assuming you actually are writing the output of the email somewhere).

Comment: That won't work in this case - the message is being handed off to a third-party client library for the actual send.  It's a reasonable idea in general though.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by pre-compiling the regexes, e.g.

```
FIXCR = re.compile(r'\r(?!\n)')
FIXLN = re.compile(r'(?<!\r)\n')
```

Then use FIXCR.sub and FIXLN.sub. Next, you could try to combine the regexes into one, with a | thingy, which should also help.

Comment: This isn't noticably faster.  I think Python must be caching the compiled regexes already.

Comment: Also, combining into one regex is considerably slower - I'm not shocked, alternation is often the slowest part of a regex engine.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Compile your regex.

```
CRLF = '\r\n'
cr_or_lf_regex = re.compile(r'(?:(?<!\r)\n)|(?:\r(?!\n))')
```

Then, when you want to replace stuff use this:

```
cr_or_lf_regex.sub(CRLF, msg)
```

**EDIT:** Since the above is actually slower, let me take another stab at it.

```
last_chr = ''

def fix_crlf(input_chr):
    global last_chr
    if input_chr != '\r' and input_chr != '\n' and last_chr != '\r':
        result = input_chr
    else:
        if last_chr == '\r' and input_chr == '\n': result = '\r\n'
        elif last_chr != '\r' and input_chr == '\n': result = '\r\n'
        elif last_chr == '\r' and input_chr != '\n': result = '\r\n%s' % input_chr
        else: result = ''

    last_chr = input_chr
    return result

fixed_msg = ''.join([fix_crlf(c) for c in msg])
```

Comment: Sooo... Did you time your new solution?  I tried something like that and it was 10x slower!  Just wondering if I did something wrong in my implementation.

Comment: Haha! Why didn't you say so? Yeah, it's like 70x slower than the solution you accepted; I just timed it now.

I'm going to say I was teaching people a lesson about blindly accepting code off the web. Also, to never search-and-replace like this in Python.